# AngularJs Ui-view can't show correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to use ui-view and ui-router in a part of my page.But for some reason I can't get to show up my template "app_usermng_table.html".
The main code of this part is as follows:

1.**router config part**

(I have add the "ui.router" dependency in my module "app" yet.)

```
.state('app.usermng', {
              url: '/usermng',
              templateUrl: 'tpl/app_usermng.html',

              resolve: {
                  deps: ['uiLoad',
                    function( uiLoad ){
                      return uiLoad.load( ['js/controllers/usermng/usermng.js','css/usermng.css'] );
                  }]
              },
              onEnter: function(){
                console.log("enter usermng");
              }
          })
          .state('app.usermng.table',{
              url:'/table',
              templateUrl:'tpl/app_usermng_table.html',
              resolve:{
                deps:[
                    'uiload',
                    function(uiload){
                      return uiload.load(['js/controllers/usermng/usermngtable.js'])
                    }
                ]
              },
              onEnter: function(){
                console.log("enter usermng table");
              }

          })
```

2.**app_usermng.html**：

I want to put the template in the

```
<div ui-view></div>
```

tag.

```
<div class="hbox hbox-auto-xs hbox-auto-sm" ng-controller="UsermngCtrl">
  <div ng-controller="UsermngCtrl">
    <div class="bg-light lter b-b wrapper-md">
      <h1 class="m-n font-thin h3">User Management</h1>
    </div>
  <div ui-view></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

3.**usermng controller**

I add the code

```
$state.transitionTo
```

hoping when I enter the state "app.usermng", the state "app.usermng.table" can be shown in its parent.

```
app.controller('UsermngCtrl',['$scope','$state',function($scope,$state){
   $state.transitionTo('app.usermng.table');
   console.log("table")
}]);
```

4.**navigation bar**

I hope it jumps to the state "app.usermng" when I click 'UserManagement' on the navigation bar.

`<li ui-sref-active="active">
    <a ui-sref="app.usermng">
      <i class="glyphicon  glyphicon-list-alt icon text-info-dker"></i>
      <span class="font-bold" translate="aside.nav.usermng">User Management</span>
    </a>
  </li>`

However,all I've done seems to be useless...The table part isn't shown.The console content is as follows:

```
enter usermng
usermng.js:3 table
usermng.js:3 table
```

It seems that my child state "app.usermng.table" never enters.

Could anyone tell me what's the problem.Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add an 'abstract':true property, like here:

```
.state('app.usermng', {
          url: '/usermng',
          templateUrl: 'tpl/app_usermng.html',
          abstract: true,
          resolve: {
              deps: ['uiLoad',
                function( uiLoad ){
                  return uiLoad.load( ['js/controllers/usermng/usermng.js','css/usermng.css'] );
              }]
          },
          onEnter: function(){
            console.log("enter usermng");
          }
      })
      .state('app.usermng.table',{
          url:'/table',
          templateUrl:'tpl/app_usermng_table.html',
          resolve:{
            deps:[
                'uiload',
                function(uiload){
                  return uiload.load(['js/controllers/usermng/usermngtable.js'])
                }
            ]
          },
          onEnter: function(){
            console.log("enter usermng table");
          }

      })
```

Comment: Thanks  a lot. I add the js file **'js/controllers/usermng/usermngtable.js'**in the resolve of state 'app.usermng' and remove $state.transitionTo in usermng.js.Then it works fine. : )

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what you are going for here. You are giving the table state a URL which makes me think you are wanting this to be a standalone state, in which case you need to just `transitionTo` that state directly instead of transitioning to the parent state. If the table state is just meant to be a piece of the parent state, there is a way to do that.

You need to use named views. If I am correct that `app.usermng.table` isn't a state in it's own right, it's a state that only exists to be shown as part of the `app.usermng` state. Therefore, when you define `app.usermng`, you need to declare the table as a named view.

```
$stateProvider
  .state('app.usermng', {
    views: {
      'table': { 
         templateUrl:'tpl/app_usermng_table.html',
         resolve: []
       }
    }
  })
```

Then, in the parent template, in the `div` where you want to insert the table, you should declare it like `<div ui-view="table"></div>`

See here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views